# Friendly urls in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have problem, I create a web app on Spring but when I make the deploy on weblogic the urls are not friendly at all, Does anybody knows how to add or create Friendly urls in weblogic  12c or if is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean "not friendly"? Examples might help.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, for example the app have a url  10.10.139.32/NearMeSection and want to change just to "nearme", but I don't want to do that on the code part

Comment: Have you played with url mapping like this? http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=790

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the web application context-root with any name of your choice.

Right-click on project and navigate to: 
*Project Properties -> Deployment -> Select War Deployment Profile -> Edit -> General*

Now set the **Java EE Web Context Root** to any name of your choice.